# Concatenate function result with sql select

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, select

I've created table rep where I store strings which are repeated in a few of my queries, example:  ('birthday_month', 'extract(month from my_table)') but there are a few much longer with CASE, and function which returns value for input key. Now I would like to concatenate sql select using records from this table.

```
select name, (select get_rep('birthday_month')) as timestep 
from my_table 
group by timestep
```

(I've just made simple example up, in real it would be more complex). But unfortunatelly it  returns

```
timestep                              count
extract(month from my_table)          12345
```

I have really a lot of common parts in my selects, so I would like to gather it in some variables..

Comment: You can't do that.  Use views instead.

Comment: You mean, instead of function? But how can I pass parameter to a view?

Comment: You can just list out all the columns you could possibly have, and then select the ones you want when you use the view.

Comment: Could you give an example in answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a view with all the columns you want:

```
create view v_my_table
     select t.*,
            extract(month from date_of_birth) as birthday_month
     from my_table t;
```

You can add as many more columns as you like.

Then use the columns that you want in a query:

```
select birthday_month, count(*)
from v_my_table
group by birthda_month;
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. It doesn't solve my problem at all because I store not only columns but it's enough for now.